# update mysql database with jdbc

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I have an error updating my database because of variables. This is my code:

```
UPDATE `payment` SET `paid`=1 AND `amoun`=$amountpaid WHERE `paid`=0 AND `userid`=$uid
```

`$amountpaid` is the amount of the bill that the user paid and `$uid` is user id. It seems like using `$` in front of variable names is forbidden. How can I use variables in SQL?

Comment: unknown column amountpaid in field list

Comment: and another error:unknown column $uid in WHERE clause

Answer (score 2):

Where are your variables coming from? You probably want something like this if you're using JDBC:

```
int setPaid = 1;
int amountPaid = x; // put $amountpaid here
int wherePaid = 0;
int userId = y; // put $uid here

String updateQuery = "UPDATE payment SET paid = ?, amoun = ?"
        + " WHERE paid = ? AND userid = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
ps.setInt(1, setPaid);
ps.setInt(2, amountPaid);
ps.setInt(3, wherePaid);
ps.setInt(4, userId);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: do we need to declare for those variables with fix value like paid=1 and paid=0?

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully make it clearer. You'll want to set the variables in Java to correspond to what you want for the `?` variables in the SQL query.

Comment: i got it...set variable for those '?' rite? thanks whitefang!!! for variable type, is it refer to variable type in database?what about if i want to update an arraylist?

Comment: Yeah, you got it. The `PreparedStatement` class has setters for a number of different variable types. It doesn't support `ArrayList` however, you'll have to find a way to store that into perhaps either a comma delimited list of strings or iterate over each item and store them as multiple rows.

Comment: let say i use longblob in database..what is the suitable variable in java?

Comment: @Roubie: I would use `byte[]` for a BLOB column

Comment: d problem is i dont want to store the data as multiple row.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using String.

I converted the `ArrayList` to a `String` and then sent the data as string. The data got updated but I don't know what will happen next if I want to view the data in the client tier...